Pyhtagorean Theorem on the surface of a $d$-dimensional sphere
This maybe a naive question, I am trying to transfer my intuition for the Euclidean space, to the space on the surface of a $d$-dimensional sphere. In the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space, (quoting a comment from @JonathanZ at  this post) the Pythagorean theorem defines the distance between two points, w.r.t. the $\ell_2$ norm. Moreover, the Pythagorean theorem can be transferred to the surface of a 3-dimensional sphere (see this post). Can we transfer the spherical Pythagorean theorem, on the surface of a $d$-dimensional sphere?
More formally, let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ be two points on the surface of a $d$-sphere. There are $H_1, \dots, H_{-1}$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$, i.e. the space in which lives the surface of the $d$-sphere. Let $\theta_i$ be the angle of the points $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ projected into the $H_i$ subspace. Can we derive a formula of the form,
$$
\measuredangle(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = f(\theta_1, \dots, \theta_{d-1}) \quad (1)?
$$
Thanks in advance for any answers, or comments. I know that this could be the case that the intuition from the Euclidean geometry does not generalize to non-Euclidean geometry. Thus any robust arguments on why the above cannot happen, or is very unlikely are also appreciated. If (1) does not hold, can we have an upper bound, substituting the equality with an inequality?

Consider how you expanded the euclidean Pythagoras from 2D to 3D etc.
$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$R^2=r^2+z^2=(x^2+y^2)+z^2$$
Same applies to spherical geometry too:
$$\cos a =\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2$$
$$\cos A =\cos a\cos\phi_3=(\cos\phi_1\cos\phi_2)\cos\phi_3$$
--- rk
PS: cf. Wikipedia - Pythagorean theorem - Non-euclidean geometry

Thank you very much for your comment! Is it that simple?The $\phi_i$s are the same as the $\theta_i$s defined above? Could you guide me through on why the above works, if it not so much to ask?

It even applies to hyperbolic space as well: $\cosh a=\cosh\phi_1\cosh\phi_2$. Here, as above the arguments of cos and cosh resp. are arc-lengths, as measured within the according geometry. And surely $\measuredangle(\phi_1,\phi_2)=\pi/2$.

An additional question, can I approximate the $\phi_i$ angles in your answer with the difference between the $i$-th coordinate in spherical coordinate $\Delta\theta_i$, i.e. $\phi_i \leq \Delta\theta_i$? Thus, bounding the great circle angle between two points by their coordinate wise angular difference, i.e. $\cos(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \leq \Pi_{i=1}^{d-1} \Delta \theta_i$?
